# How to make input() consider an entire string to insert into a list?

Tags: python, list, input, printing

Hello I'm learning python and when I got to the lists I decided to try something like this:

An input to receive the full name of a user and a print to return the surname as a welcome.

```
nome = []
nome = input("Enter your full name ")
print("Welcome Mr. ", nome[2] )
```

But the `input` is inserting every character as a new item of the list so the result is "I" since I'm typed "LOIP CANVAS" and "I" is the number 2 of the list.

Detailing:

```
[0] [1] [2] [3]                 
[L] [O] [I] [P]
```

But I want to print is the 2nd word and not the 2nd character in the list...

The question is: **How to use `input` to add an entire word as new item of a list?**

Comment: FYI, Python indexes items counting from `0`, so the _second_ item has an index  of `[1]`. Also, `input()` returns a string (a sequence of characters), not a list of them.

Comment: Oh i understand now, thanks @martineau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split`:

```
print("Seja bem vindo Sr. ", nome.split()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The below representation explains what are you doing currently in your code :

```
1. nome = []
2. nome = input("Digite seu nome completo ")
3. print("Seja bem vindo Sr. ", nome[2] )
```

**STEP 1 :**

[image: step 1]

**STEP 2 :**

[image]

**STEP 3 :**

[image]

But, instead what you can do is, you can split the full name that you are getting as an input into two separate strings. Python provides split() method that splits a string into a list.You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace. And once you have the list of first name (primeiro nome) and last name (sobrenome), you have to access the second item of the list. you can refer to the code and explanation below :

```
1. nome = []
2. nome = input("Digite seu nome completo ")
3. lista_de_nomes = nome.split()
4. sobrenome = lista_de_nomes[1]
5. print("Seja bem vindo Sr. ", sobrenome )
```

**STEP 1:**

[image]

**STEP 2:**

[image]

**STEP 3:**

[image]

**STEP 4:**

[image]

Comment: This is so well explained, thank you! I was thinking if its possible to use the split inside the input to directly set the value of a variable as the second name inserted to resume even more the code, something like:

```nome = input.split(1)("Digite seu nome completo ")``` do you know a way to do this?

Comment: The input() method reads a line from input, converts into a string and returns it. So, if you want, you can give a try to apply split() on the result of input() as -      ```input("Enter a string").split()``` This will return a list of two strings. So, finally what you would like to do will be - ```input("Enter a string").split()[1]```.

Comment: Totally work! Thanks.. Upvoted you of course :)

Solution:
```nome = []
nome = input("Digite seu nome completo").split()[1]
print("Seja bem vindo Sr.",nome)```